# Test Domain Using Existing DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, domain

Server A, Domain Controller with DNS Server and Exchange 2010 (domainA) Server B, New Server going to add AD DS role for new test domain and Exchange 2013. I want this to be a new domain but i want to use the DNS from Server A....

How do I go about doing this correctly? Do I add a new Forward Lookup Zone before the ADDS role is created? I would like to only maintain one DNS server and when I go to create the AD DS role I have some interesting questions to answer...Do I set up the DNS options during the Promotion to Domain Controller steps? I am confused and cannot find actual steps.

During Deployment configuration I set up "Add a new forest" and then I name my domain. In the domain controller options I have a checkbox for Domain Name System(DNS) server but I never added this role to Server B.

I guess what I am asking if I need to set up a second domain to test Exchange 2013 for an application and I cannot use my current domain since I cannot have two exchange servers on the same domain, do I set up the domain role and how do I do this while staying with one DNS server?

Comment: Do a new install with dns serveronce it is all working setup consider  dns zone transfer.

Comment: Exchange 2013 CU2 will coexist in the same AD domain with Exchange 2010 SP3, so why are you building a separate AD domain? Why do you want domainB to use domainA DNS? The simplest and easiest method is to install DNS with AD DS on the same server in domainB. You're making this more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @joeqwerty when I try to install Exchange 2013 on my domain I cannot get the installer to go through as it complains there is another Exchange on that domain, I can try again and make sure my Exchange 2010 is on SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to create DNS server for test domain on server B. It is standard and easy setup. If you want server A DNS service to resolve test domain, add it to server A and specify Server B as NS.